# Function stops at for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

When I run the following code, I don't get either print statement within the for loop. The value of `q` is never printed. But if I make a `range` and do the same thing in REPL, it works.

```
def main():
    startpoint = 1100000
    qs = range(startpoint, startpoint - 100)
    print("qs = %s" % qs)
    print("Approaching for loop")
    for q in enumerate(qs):
        print("Successfully entered for loop")
        print(q)
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What is stopping the above code from functioning?

Comment: And what's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your range is an empty generator/list (depending on python version).
This happened because stop is less than start. 
Use a third argument, to step down.

```
# range(start, stop, step)
qs = range(startpoint, startpoint - 100, -1)
```

Comment: `start is less than stop` -- I think you have that backwards.

Comment: I feel like an absolute idiot. I'll accept once SO allows me.